# Location of error log for restore operation

Tags: restore

I try to perform a restore using stsadm. When the operation completes, I get the following message: Restore failed for Object [Sharepoint Database Name] in event OnPostRestore. For more information, see the error log located in the backup directory.
However, I am unable to find the error log. What is the "backup directory" that the message mentions?
Also, it appears like the error has to do with my SP database. What could be causing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default all Sharepoint errors are logged in the 12-hive in a folder called LOGS. If you haven't changed this path manually, they should still exist in that folder (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\LOGS).

The path can be changed in the Operations tab of Central Admin.
There's a block for Logging where you can change the path.